# In web service, how to change the interface without updating the client?

Tags: web-services, web, service, architecture

In the book 'Java web services' by Chappell and Jewell, it describes loosely coupled being one of the characteristics of web services.  It went on to state the following:

"The web service interface can change over time without compromising the client's ability to interact with the service."

My question is, how can the web service interface change without changing the client?  From a coding perspective, if an interface change (new parameter, new name etc..), the caller needs to update the code accordingly.  Can someone help me interpret the above statement?

Comment: The author probably writes about the problem of change the specification of a web service without breaking backward compatibility for those clients that will not upgrade to the new interface. Of course, if a requestor wants to use the new or updated service, it needs to refactor its code.

Comment: You may want to summarize the arguments of the author and the kind of "web services" he is talking about if you want a detailed answer. For example A REST service is not as rigid as a SOAP service

Answer (score 0):

I think they actually mean the implementation of the interface but used a poor and confusing description in the book.

When a web service is published and consumers begin to use it, you can no longer change the interface of the web service without breaking those consumers.

The web service is a contract. It is not possible to rename parameters, change the response or update the URL and keep everything operational without changing the clients.